# examples of closed questions

Tags: support, closed-questions

I've read [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) and I found this:

> Common reasons a question may be closed include:
>
> - exact duplicate
> - off topic
> - not constructive
> - not a real question
> - too localized

Can you show me some examples of question that are being closed and each are concern with one of this common reasons!

Comment: One example , [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558302/two-ways-of-assigning-a-buttons-onclick-method) question was an exact duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3a1

Comment: _"Do you love me?" -> NARQ. "Let's go shopping" -> N/C. "What dress to wear today?" -> T/L. "Why didn't you listen to me?" -> O/T. "My mama told" -> dupe of "My mama is always wrong"_ ([BTDTGTTS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175374/what-is-the-procedure-for-having-my-spouse-significant-other-as-a-member-of-the#comment526067_175374 "quoted from here"))

Answer (score 2):

Examples of questions that are closed for

[Exact duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271032/ios-keyboard-shows-save)

[Off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973662/pybbm-installation)

[Not constructive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459039/where-to-follow-trending-designs-for-ios-development)

[Not a real question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888685/what-is-the-proper-way-to-learn-php-and-other-computer-languages)

[Too localized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107904/how-to-determine-an-iphone-app-using-webview-or-not)